# How to add custom colors to dates in Calendar View of Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-layout, user-interface

Currently, I'm developing an Andriod app for Attendance Management System. For showing the attendace to the Users whether they were "Present" or "Absent" on the particular day by differentiating them using red and green color. I've no idea how to do it.

I've tried using "zcustomcalendar" for that functionality. But ended up in "Failed to resolve: org.naishadhparmar.zcustomcalendar:zcustomcalendar:1.0.1" error. [image: This was the error that I've received]

The below are the dependencies that I've used in my project.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'org.naishadhparmar.zcustomcalendar:zcustomcalendar:1.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```xml
maven {
    url 'https://jitpack.io'
}
```

in your project level gradle